# Create SQL linked server connection to server outside of a network

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to create a linked server connection to a server that lies outside of our network inside of SQL Server Management Studio. I have the IP address, the port, the name of the server, and a username and password to connect to the server. I have attempted to use the linked server wizard and have tried putting the IP address in the 'Linked server' field as IP:Port, which didn't work, then put that same combination into the 'Data source' field. I have not been able to find any guidance on how to do this or if it is even possible to link a server outside of the network. Is this possible? If so, how am I supposed to create the connection?

Edit 1:
The error that I get is error code 87, that it cannot connect.
What I mean by outside of my network is that the server is owned by another organization, therefore I need to connect to it using the IP address, instead of using the name of the server, since it is not on our domain.

Edit 2:
I discovered that I was apparently entering the data in wrong before. I was able to create the connection using 'IP, Port#' in the 'Linked server' field, using the default SQL Server radio option and placed the username and password in the security tab.

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: "Outside of a network" also doesn't say anything. Unless you are asking how to connect to a remote server using VPN

Comment: this may help you in getting help faster and also upvotes as well :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Let's start with the basics.  If you remote desktop into your *source* server and run SSMS (Management Studio), can you then connect directly to that *target* server outside of your network with SSMS?

Comment: @TheGameiswar That article doesn't really apply as this is a DBA question, and not anything to do with T-SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Linked Server with non-default port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445125/how-to-create-linked-server-with-non-default-port)

Comment: @RBarryYoung:i think this is generalized on how to to asking

Comment: @TheGameiswar Not really.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I cannot remote into the server. All I have is a username and password to connect to the database, not the server. We do not own the server.

Comment: @JustinFoley No, remote into *your* server, the *source* server.  Then try to connect to *their* SQL server (the *target* SQL server) with SSMS from *your* server.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I am able to connect to their server.

Comment: Is the target DBMS also SQL Server.  If so, what version is it and what version is yours?

Comment: You need to have a Trust established between the domains you are trying to connect to. Contact your network administrator.